# Query for Customer ledger report with opening and closing balance

Tags: ms-access

I prepared an accounting db in access 2010. All is working well except the customer ledger report. For less data it is ok but if records are in hundreds then it takes long to calculate the result.

I use "union all" to join some tables and queries to create final ledger. "RunningSum" achieved in report built-in function. In the report header the previous balance shows in a text field using DSUM function as =DSUM("[debit-credit]","prev_balance"). Then the actual data shows between "DateFrom" and "DateTO". The balance of each record shows the "RunningBalance" + "PreviousBalance" from text box. So the calculation of DSUM being done on every record so take long long time.
I need a query which show the "previous balance" in first row then the records between required dates. I could do it using UNION of two queries, one showing sum of dr-cr before DateFrom and second shows the data between required dates. Problem is that how can I get the word "Opening Balance" in first row narration because first query gives me only the sum amount of all records. The narration field have various entries so can not be GROUP BY.
Please give me a sql query code to do it. You can use columns like this; id, date, ac_id, narration, dr, cr, balance from "final_ledger". If it is not possible in ms access I can shift to MySQL if you suggest. If you have problem understanding what I exactly need I can upload an example copy of my db.

Comment: SO is a "coding assistance" forum. All info to analyze an issue should be included within question, not downloadable files. Provide sample data as formatted text table in question. Might want to post in a forum that allows attaching files. What you want might require VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I reached on a solution of the problem. I created a query which gives me the sum of [Dr]-[Cr] before DateFrom as opening or previous balance. Then another query which shows the records between two dates. I made a union query of these two. First query returns only one record so a new column was created which have value "Opening Balance". Then designed a report taking data from this union query. Now there is no delay in populating the report.